# Place holder in text area not applied in IE alone?

Tags: html, css, zk

I am using the following code,

```
<textbox value="abc" placeholder="Eg:sample" rows="7"/>

CSS:
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: blue;
}
```

While render in browser, the textbox renders as "textarea" and in Chrome,Firefox placeholder color sets fine. In IE(version9) alone, it renders font color instead of placeholder color.

Please anyone help with this.

Comment: placeholder is not supported by IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember: Internet Explorer 9 is ancient. Internet Explorer 9 is buggy. Internet Explorer 9 has very low market share.

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) shows that support for `:-ms-input-placeholder` was added in Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: Can you please the difference between :-ms-input-placeholder and input:-ms-input-placeholder? Which I can prefer to be supported by all browsers?

Comment: `input` matches `<input>` elements. Very little is supported by "all browsers". Some stuff is just too new and some browsers are just too ancient.